# Countif function in VBA that refers to a table column by name?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having as issue trying to refer to a table column name in a countif statement.  I have a table `TBL_Client1` with multiple column names.  I have three slicers that can be selected to narrow down my table to 1 row.  I'm using the first column `Visible` in the table to identify when the table has been selected down to one row. I'm Currently using this code on a button to trigger another button visibility.  It works but the table I have is dynamic and could use more and more rows.  How can I refer to the table column name instead of `a1:a1500`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim n As Integer
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("a1:a1500"), "1")
If (n) = 1 Then
Sheets("clientlist").CommandButton2.Visible = True
Else
Sheets("clientlist").CommandButton2.Visible = False
End If
```

I'm using this to make a button visible `CommandButton2`.  `CommandButton2` once visible executes a copy function that once again, I cant figure out how to reference a table column by name instead of referring to a row number.  The following is my next macro:

```
Sub update()
A = Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To A
If Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 1).Value = "1" Then
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 2).Copy
    b = Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("clientlist").Paste 
Destination:=Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 2)
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 3).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(10, 11).Copy
    Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 4).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 11).Copy
    Worksheets("clientlist").Paste 
Destination:=Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 7)
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 12).Copy
    Worksheets("clientlist").Paste 
Destination:=Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 6)
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(i, 13).Copy
    Worksheets("clientlist").Paste 
Destination:=Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 5)
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(3, 11).Copy
    Worksheets("clientlist").Paste 
Destination:=Worksheets("contactlog").Cells(b + 1, 8)
    c = Worksheets("deals").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("clientlist").Cells(10, 11).Copy
    Worksheets("deals").Cells(c + 1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Finally, I'm using 2 buttons and visibility only because I cant figure out how to get a Macro to run continuously.  I've been searching through the web (especially StackOverflow) for about 2 weeks now and I'm getting close, but just not quite as Dynamic as I feel it could be.  Ultimately I would like the visibility of the button to be triggered anytime something is selected on a slicer.  I already tried the change and update but since the actual information on the table itself is not changing the code I've tried hasn't worked.  And I would like to copy/countif/paste referring to table column names instead of row numbers and column numbers.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Range("TBL_Client1[your-column-name]")`

That should do the trick.

Comment: When I use this structure I get and Error '1004', Method'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Private Sub commandbutton1_click()
Dim n As Integer
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("tbl_client1[visible]"), "1")
    If (n) = 1 Then
    Sheets("clientlist").CommandButton2.Visible = True
    Else
    Sheets("clientlist").CommandButton2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Never mind I didn't have the spelling correct for my table.  It should have been "tbl_clients1".  Thanks for your help